# Authentication error while accessing smb nas (Macos Big Sur)

Tags: macos, smb, nas

I am having a really bad time setting up an old nas I had never used. My knowledge is quite limited but I managed to gather some information about my problem.

I am using a medion nas that uses smb1 I believe. I can access it no problem with windows 10 after enabling smb1, even login as registered user worked just fine. But for my mac, it fails every time to login as a registered user. I tried multiple users, even matching the user & password of the mac but nothing is working. What is weird is that I can access some shared (public) files as a guest.

Mac : mackbook pro 2013 os : 11.6.7.

Nas : MEDION LIFE P89637

Method used : smb://serverIp & cifs://serverIp

Is there a way to troubleshoot this issue or is it an obvious error ?

Comment: Hi, during that time I bought a Drobo NAS because of the smb compatibility to the Mac for a Time machine backup. After a short time Apple extend / (changed) the SMB protocol so my NAS was useless. After a second period Drobo patched the enhanced protocol to be compatible..... This takes two or three rounds. So to summarize. The only chance is to update your NAS software for the Medion, because the SMB protocol from Apple was extended  and is not compatible... My Drobois in my store for some years... But this is also an experience from the past.....

Comment: @popeinvestor from what I know there is no update available for my Nas (it is quite old). What is weird is that I can still access/write it as a guest. If the protocol wasn’t supported would I still be able to do that ?

Comment: I used my NAS as a backup storage. There I had problems with the smb protocol and time machine. So I was able to use it as a device from my Mac but not for time machine backups. My objective was only to give you the hint with apple and smb, that it might not be compatible.....